# The difference between to fry and to braise

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

What is the difference between *to fry* and *to braise*. According to the internet, both means cooking something in oil without soaking in it.

I watched different videos on youtube using these words but it seems like they do the same thing .For example fry pan steak and braised steak.

Comment: Doesn't braising involve a secondary stewing phase which frying does not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frying is cooking by immersion in oil—either total immersion, or partial immersion on each side.

Braising is a two-stage process: the food is first either seared in a dry pan or browned in a little oil, and then cooked slowly in a simmering aqueous (non-fat) liquid.

Comment: But there are lots of kind of frying: "[deep fry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deep-fry#Verb)", "[flash fry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flash-fry#Verb)", "[pan fry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pan-fry#Verb)", "[shallow fry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shallow-fry#Verb)", "[stir fry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stir-fry#Verb)" and not all involve immersion. Well I suppose "partial immersion" might cover that (-: Still these different frying techniques and terms may be useful for people interested in this question.